# Constructing an AC clamp ammeter

Tags: current, inductance, toroid

How many turns needed on a donut ferrite core to produce 5 volts when one conductor of a 240 volt AC cable is threaded through it? What size of ferrite should I use and what diameter of wire?. I'll use the 5 volts either to light an LED or else to feed to a microcontroller input. If 5 volts is an impractical target then enough to trigger a microcontroller input would be good enough. The "project" is to let me know when my oil-filled electric heater is using power as it has no visible indicator such as a nice red LED. I'll build this device inside an insulated box using all safety principles (C&G Industrial Electronics Technician)

Comment: Use the term “current transformer “ in a google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How many turns needed on a donut ferrite core to produce 5 volts when
> one conductor of a 240 volt AC cable is threaded through it?*

It's got nothing to do with the 240 volts; it's got everything to do with the current flowing through the cable that passes through the toroid ferrite. So, if the current is 1 amp RMS and you had a secondary winding of 1000 turns, you'd get 1 mA flowing when you short it.

That doesn't mean 1000 turns will work and doesn't mean 100 turns will work because we know nothing about your load current range.

BTW, I'd use two anti-wired LEDs on the secondary output but, make sure you design the number of turns that copes with the primary load current and, that primary current doesn't rise so high that it blows the LEDs.

Comment: In my post I referred to an electric heater and 2Kw is a fairly standard item. I calculated that it will be drawing about 8 amperes. My need is only to sense whether or not power is being used and my requirement for 5 volts is because its the sort of voltage I find in my electronic dabbling. I downloaded a very informative pdf from Coilcraft which informed me that in current sensing applications a single turn often suffices for the primary. They also reminded me of the transformer equation which I had forgotten and which you are familiar with. Thanks for the tip about the anti-wired LEDS.

Comment: @GregoryMartin if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.